# Why are my Windows networked machines not finding any wireless networks?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

At home, we have a wireless network that has about 10 people connected to it. Every few hours or so, someone calls me over because a computer has lost their wireless connection and won't reconnect.

When I look at the wireless pop-up, it doesn't show any networks, despite the fact there are about 10 within range normally.

After disabling and enabling the wireless device, it can 'see' all of the wireless points once more.

What could be causing this issue?

All machines are running Windows and the machine is occurs on is seemingly random.

Comment: Changed, as requested.

Comment: Great. Now, can you add details about the device you are all connecting to? Also, does this seem to be the same computer(s) having this problem or is it random. Is it limited to a specific OS?

Comment: "10 people connected to it"...how big is your family? lol. Are all 10 people using the same desktop/laptop model and OS? Please clarify the total devices and their OS. If these are 10 identical desktops then I would suspect a faulty wireless NIC.

Comment: Everyone is using various versions of Windows, with different machine.